# Autentication in Rest

Tags: rest-api

I have a local installation of Magento 2 where everything is configured and all the API works fine

I'm doing an app for a client also with Magento 2
Done the same confugurations
And the site always returns
Consumer is not authorized to access %resources
There is anyconfiguration in Magento that we need to configure?

If we give the Guest Access, everything works

We'checked the access keys and every are correct

We use
ConsumerKey
ConsumerSecret
AccessToken
AccessTokenSecret

Comment: Have you setup the API configuration in the admin panel?

Comment: Of course I've made the setup of the API configuration, and that works fine in my local instalation of Magento, I can't access to a site in the WEB. I believe there is any configuration in the server that does not allow me to access the REST API, if you look well, the anwer is that "Consumer is not authorized to access", this is an answer from REST.

Comment: When you do requests do you also include the Authorization param and also does have you included "Bearer" and a blank space between consumer secret?